# Rails - track application memory usage on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How can I monitor memory usage(between requests, overall RAM usage etc) on local environment? Are there any gems available for it?

Thanks

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/binarylogic/memorylogic)

Comment: Hi @mohitmun, did you find something useful? I have a rails app in heroku crashing because memory leaks :(